# JUnit4 test runner

Tags: java, class, junit, program-entry-point

My Java test do not compile, I run it and have:

> no junit tests
>   could not find main class (specified in run-configuration)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332832/no-tests-found-with-test-runner-junit-4

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `@Test` methods in your class.

JUnit4 looks for methods annotated with `@Test` - if it doesn't find any in a class, it omits that class completely.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter

```
@Test 
    public void testSomeBehavior() { 
        assertEquals("Empty list should have 0 elements", 0, emptyList.size()); 
    }
```

Comment: my code is correct it worked yesterday I have not make any modification in code