# Finding all tests in a subpackage

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit4

When I try running JUnit tests, I get the error message

> No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 4'

and therefore I have tried solutions from

- [No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332832/no-tests-found-with-test-runner-junit-4)
- [junit: no tests found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469480/junit-no-tests-found)
- ['No JUnit tests found' in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057771/no-junit-tests-found-in-eclipse)

However, in my case, the difference seems to be that I specify the tests to run on **package level** instead of folder level.

Running JUnit tests works if I specify a package that directly contains test classes (e.g. `com.example.tests.smoketests`) but does not work if a higher level package is specified (e.g. `com.example.tests`).

If I define a test in `com.example.tests`, it is found and run.

Is there a way to let Eclipse/JUnit find tests in a package and all subpackages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, there is nothing to do this for you. You can use the [`Suite`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html) annotation to achieve this goal in JUnit4, though this still requires you to manually define a Suite test for each package, and then include all of them in a aggregate Suite test (such they recursively call child Suites).

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import a.sub.package.AnotherSuiteTest.class;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   PackageLocalTestClass1.class,
   PackageLocalTestClass2.class,
   AnotherSuiteTest.class
})
public class JunitTestSuite {   
}
```

I've played around with building my own utility class before which creates the entire series of tests. [This article](http://www.anzaan.com/2012/01/automatic-unit-testing-test-packages-recursively-in-junit/) provides an analogous utility.

Comment: FYI: The code in the link you provided has several issues (finds non-test classes / having several DynamicSuite annotated classes is buggy).

Comment: Sorry, @Thomas, I only did a cursory review, and it had the same "look and feel" of what I was trying to convey. :)