# JUnit TestNotFound Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, runner, jsystem

I created test in Eclipse with annotation test and ran cleanInstall. Then tried to run it in JSystem Runner but TestNotFound Exception Was Found.

The test was found in JSystem But failed to run with TestNotFound - Seems like code or something wasn't loaded correctly.

My Exception:

```
   java.lang.Exception: Test not found
at junit.framework.ExecutionErrorTests.testNotFound(ExecutionErrorTests.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:105)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:98)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
at junit.framework.JSystemJUnit4ClassRunner.run(JSystemJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)
at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapterForJSystem.run(JUnit4TestAdapterForJSystem.java:86)
at com.aqua.anttask.jsystem.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:461)
at com.aqua.anttask.jsystem.JSystemTask.executeInVM(JSystemTask.java:1388)
at com.aqua.anttask.jsystem.JSystemTask.execute(JSystemTask.java:957)
at com.aqua.anttask.jsystem.JSystemTask.executeOrQueue(JSystemTask.java:1806)
at com.aqua.anttask.jsystem.JSystemTask.execute(JSystemTask.java:897)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:416)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.AntCallBack.execute(AntCallBack.java:54)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

My Test:

```
public class DpUtilization extends BaseBBClass{


    private int value  = -1;

    private DpUtil dpUtil = null;

    public DpUtil getDpUtil() {
        return dpUtil;
    }

    @ParameterProperties(section = "Dp Utilization", description = "Choose Dp Utilization")
    public void setDpUtil(DpUtil dpUtil) {
        this.dpUtil = dpUtil;
    }


    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @ParameterProperties(section = "Dp Utilization", description = "Set Value")
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Test
    @TestProperties(name = "check DP Utilization", paramsInclude = { "DpUtil", "value"})
    public void testdpUtilization() throws Exception
    {
        report.report("final value: " + checkDpUtilization());
    }

}
```

My BaseClass:

```
public class BaseBBClass extends SystemTestCase4
{       

    @Override
    public void defaultBefore() throws Throwable
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void defaultAfter() throws Throwable
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you shure, that you imported the correct @Test annotation?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057771/no-junit-tests-found-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.
The problem was that the test should return only void!

Comment: But your code in the question has a `@Test public void` method only?

Comment: There was another test in same class with Return value "boolean" which affected all class tests jar

Comment: I see.... well next time you ask make sure to include all relevant code. Makes troubleshooting much easier :-)