# STS 3.9.2 - Eclipse Oxigen (4.7.2) - Unable to run JUnit 5 tests java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory

Tags: eclipse, junit, spring-tool-suite, junit5, eclipse-oxygen

I am unable to run JUnit 5 tests in a **JDK 8** project:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherFactory
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.<init>(JUnit5TestLoader.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:205)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717693/eclipse-no-tests-found-using-junit-5-caused-by-noclassdeffounderror) but it applies to JDK 9 projects which is not my case.

Is there any workaround to be able to launch the tests within the IDE?

Comment: Did you try to solve it like described there? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47101722/1431016

Comment: Thanks @Sormuras, it worked