# junit-jupiter-engine v5.0.1 not working with eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Tags: eclipse, junit5, eclipse-oxygen, junit-jupiter

I stumbled upon this exception while running a junit test class (versions in question title).

[image]

As i have read in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717693/eclipse-no-tests-found-using-junit-5-caused-by-noclassdeffounderror) that i must upgrade to eclipse Oxygen.3, i did it but still have the same exception thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the platform is missing in your pom.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
     <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Exactly what is missing !