# Eclipse keep saying "No tests found with test runner JUnit 5"

Tags: eclipse, junit, junit5

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3). The following is my JUnit test class:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

class MyMathTest {
    MyMath myMath = new MyMath();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("Before");
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("After");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSum_with3numbers() {
        System.out.println("Test1");
        int result = myMath.sum(new int[] {1,2,3});
        int expected = 6;
        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSum_with1numbers() {
        System.out.println("Test2");
        int result = myMath.sum(new int[] {3});
        int expected = 3;
        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Before class");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("After class");
    }

}
```

When I run this Junit test, eclipse keeps popping up dialog telling **"No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'"**. Why?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse No tests found using JUnit 5 caused by NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717693/eclipse-no-tests-found-using-junit-5-caused-by-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: `@Test`should be at class level I think.

Comment: You seem to be using JUnit 4 annotations from the org.junit package instead of JUnit Jupiter annotations from the org.junit.jupiter.api package.

Answer (score 19):

Your test class is currently based on JUnit 4 since it uses annotations from the `org.junit` package.

Thus, to get it to run as a JUnit 4 test class in Eclipse, you need to select the JUnit 4 Runner in the "Run Configuration". Click on the tiny arrow (pointing down) next to the green circle with a white arrow in it (at the top of the Eclipse IDE). There you should see your test class, and by selecting that you can switch between the JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 runners.

On the other hand, if your goal is to write a test using JUnit Jupiter (i.e., the programming model for JUnit 5), you'll need to switch from annotations in `org.junit` to `org.junit.jupiter.api`.

Comment: It's a good point, however, this part seems to have got buggy somehow in eclipse; I tried with both annotations and both frameworks and the message keeps appearing; and I tried with several solutions in this thread and it keeps appearing. 

I also realised, it this mattered, that the project was not added in the source tab, in the run configuration, but adding it there didn't help.

It's kinda frustrating because you wanna be a good boy and write your tests, and you struggle for a while with this and yet not get it going.

Comment: I have just realised that there is a comment on the first question stating a possible duplicate; have a looke if you didin't realise. 

The problem here is if you run a custom version of eclipse, e.g. sts or codeready, you'll be lagging behind (maybe). Still, after realising about this I need to install a new eclipse ... sigh

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error, after trying everything, I have realized that the JUnit library wasn't added. So after adding it, tests worked as intended.

[image]

Comment: this solution worked perfectly for me. Add Junit library to your project and run again.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me because my test method was declared as private and JUnit could not detect it. After I made it public it worked as expected, of course with @Test annotation.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) is a bug that can cause the "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'" error:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551298

I added the following dependency to my project and it worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

the test class is not public, make it public and it should work

Answer (score 2):

You are using JUnit 4 annotations with JUnit 5 dependencies.
If you want to use JUnit 5 you should replace:

```
@Before with @BeforeEach
@After with @AfterEach
@BeforeClass with @BeforeAll
@AfterClass with @AfterAll
@Ignore with @Disabled
```

Here is more about JUnit 5 annotations https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look back to your imports.

You imports `import org.junit.Test;` (Used for run test cases with JUnit 4)

You need to import `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` to run tast case with JUnit5.

Comment: Thanks much, this is the only solution that worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the java file and choose:

**Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Java Build Path**.

Choose the tab **Libraries** in Java Build Path, On the right side tab choose **Add Library**.

Select **JUnit** and click **Next**.

Choose **JUnit 5** in **JUnit Library version** dropdown and click **finish**.

Now run the Test with **Junit Test**, it will work.

This procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

right click and run as -> config-> make this change and run it will works cheers!!.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

Right click on project -> Configure -> Add module-info -> Give some random name.
It should automatically add there a requires in the JUnit package, if not, then manually add this:

```
requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
```

And it will magically work!

** tested on Eclipse 2018-12*

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that, Run works fine, debug throws this error.

I was getting this merely because of low memory in the system. Ideally, eclipse couldn't launch the debug session due to low memory in the system. Error message thrown is confusing.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In my current case, I encountered this error when testing the pact verification on the Service Provider side.The error was thrown because the Pact Broker doesn't have any pact to test against the Service Provider.

Visit the pact broker and ensure that there is at least one pact to test with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Eclipse (2020-09) non-Maven project. None of the proposed solutions worked, but changing the compiler from 9.0.4 to 15.0.1 did.

I did that by selecting `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`and checking the box next to `jdk-15.01`. You may need to install a recent JDK if none are shown.

Comment: How did you change the compiler? Some steps you followed would help here.

Comment: @jason-hernandez-73 Done.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the JUnit vintage dependency fixed the issue for me.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-running

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if a class of the exact same name exists in both the `main` and `test` parts of the source code and the former does not contain test code, e.g. if you have

1. src/main/some/package/structure/SomeTest.java (no test code)
2. src/test/some/package/structure/SomeTest.java (actual test code)

Eclipse will fail to run the second class with the JUnit 5 test runner and show the error

> No tests found with test runner JUnit 5

(Eclipse 4.27 / 2023-07)