# Import org.junit.Test throws error as "No Test found with Test Runner "JUnit 5""

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

If I import `org.junit.Test` then on running JUnit, it gives me an error as "No Test found with Test Runner JUnit 5".

Instead if I import `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` then I can run JUnit test.

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `org.junit.Test` is a JUnit 4 annotation. A Junit5 test runner **will not** discover a test annotated with `org.junit.Test`.

A Junit5 test runner **will** discover a test annotated with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

So, this explains why you get "*No Test found with Test Runner JUnit 5*" when attempting to run a test context which does not contain any tests annotated with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

It *sounds like* you might be migrating from Junit4 to Junit5. If so, there are several changes you'll need to come to terms with. The [Junit5 docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) offer some useful tips including:

> Annotations reside in the `org.junit.jupiter.api` package.
>
> Assertions reside in `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions`.
>
> Assumptions reside in `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions`.
>
> `@Before` and `@After` no longer exist; use `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach`
>   instead.
>
> `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` no longer exist; use `@BeforeAll` and
>   `@AfterAll` instead.
>
> `@Ignore` no longer exists: use `@Disabled` or one of the other built-in
>   execution conditions instead
>
> `@Category` no longer exists; use `@Tag` instead.
>
> `@RunWith` no longer exists; superseded by `@ExtendWith`.
>
> `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` no longer exist; superseded by `@ExtendWith` and
>   `@RegisterExtension`