# Error while executing JUnit test in spring boot using STS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I am getting below exception while running Junt test in STS along with a popup :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Popup Message:

No Tests found with test runner ‘Junit5’

Tried:
[Junit STS - No test found with test runner 'Junit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104717/junit-sts-no-test-found-with-test-runner-junit-5)

None of the solutions seems to be working for me . The same test class works fine for other people hence the error is specific to my IDE.

Test case structure:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
Class TestClass {

@BeforeAll
Public static void setup() {
//code
}


@Test
@Order(1)
Void test1() {

}

@Test
@Order(2)
Void test2() {

}


}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>abc-xxx</name>
    <description>Spring boot Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.18</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!--    <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!--       <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RDF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdf4j-sparqlbuilder</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdf4j-repository-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API Documentation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- miscellaneous -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Beta2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Beta2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yyy</groupId>
            <artifactId>yyy-zzz</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bbb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bbb-uuu</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>com.ccc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ccc-hhh</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ddd</groupId>
            <artifactId>ddd-yyy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <spotbugsXmlOutput>true</spotbugsXmlOutput>
                    <threshold>Medium</threshold>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please show your build.gradle or pom.xml file.

Comment: @ johanneslink Added pom.xml!

Comment: And executing `mvn test` on e.g. a terminal works?

Answer (score 0):

Trying addinng junit5 maven dependency in your pom.xml :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: JUnit 5 is already included by `spring-boot-starter-test`