# junit: no tests found

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I have inherited a Java project and am new to Java development. I feel a good way for me to get comfortable with the code is to write some tests around it. I'm writing my code using IntelliJ.

My existing project has a folder structure like this:

```
/myProject
  /src
    /main
      /java
        /com.lexcorp
          /core
            /email
              /providers
                emailProvider.java
```

I created a new project that will hold tests for this project. I would like this project to hold both unit and integration tests. Currently, my new project has a structure like this:

```
/myProjectTests
  /src
    /main
      /java
        /com.lexcorp.core.email.providers
          emailProviderTest.java
```

The emailProviderTest.java file looks like the following:

```
package com.lexcorp.core.email.providers;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EmailProviderTest extends TestCase {

    private final String username = "[testAccount]";

    private final String password = "[testPassword]";

    @Test
    public void thisAlwaysPasses() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

This project has a Run/Debug configuration with the following properties:

- Test kind: All in package
- Search for tests: In whole project

When I run this configuration, I get an error that says:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.lexcorp.core.email.providers.EmailProviderTest
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I do not understand why I'm getting an error that boils down to: "No tests found". While my project structures differ, the folder structures on the OS match (which is another thing that confuses me). Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I was getting this error, too:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in ...

The reason was that I forgot to specify

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

After syncing the project, it found the tests. So maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: Is there a way to combine with this //testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"?

Comment: Still a helpful hint. For Jetpack this will work:
``testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"``

Answer (score 44):

Extending `junit.framework.TestCase` is the old JUnit 3 approach of implementing test cases which doesnt work as no methods start with the letters *test*. Since you're using JUnit 4, just declare the class as

```
public class EmailProviderTest {
```

and the test method will be found from the `@Test` annotation.

Read: [JUnit confusion: use 'extend Testcase' or '@Test'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extend-testcase-or-test)

Comment: When I remove the `extends TestCase` I get a compile-time error that says: java: cannot find symbol symbol: method assertTrue(boolean).

Comment: different issue: you're missing the static import `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue`

Comment: true, just remove the "extends TestCase()" and the Tests runs!

Answer (score 30):

I was getting this too:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in ...

Solved by renaming the test method from **method1**

```
@Test
public void method1(){
    // Do some stuff...
}
```

to **testMethod1**

```
@Test
public void testMethod1(){
    // Do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: Amazing fix, no once can even image this.

Comment: Actually that was a documented behavior. It is obsolete since JUnit4, though.

Answer (score 11):

if you are using jUnit 4 then not use **extends TestCase**, removing this fixed error.

Comment: fantastic. it fixed

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, in Intellij IDEA, for Java framework.
I was doing all right:

- the class inherited from TestCase
- I've imported junit.framework.TestCase
- I've add the decoration @Test

But I did one thing wrong: the name of the method **didn't start with "test"**, in fact was:

```
@Test
public void getSomethingTest(){
```

and when I changed it into:

```
@Test
public void testGetSomethingTest(){
```

I've resolved:  the executor was finally able to recognize this method as a test method.
**I've changed nothing else.**

Comment: Worked for me in Intellij.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into the situation in `JUnit 5` when created a `private` method:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class Test1 {

    @Test
    private fun sort() {
        println("1")
    }
}
```

Remove `private`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed `junit4-version.jar` in the classpath of the task *junit* and also:

```
ant-version.jar
ant-junit-version.jar
ant-junit4-version.jar
```

at the library of my ant installation (`/usr/share/ant/lib`).

I was getting the error "*junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in ...*" while I hadn't had `ant-junit4-*version*.jar` in the right place.

I corrected this by installing *ant-optional* debian/ubuntu package:

```
apt-get install ant-optional
```

Comment: I just used both ant-junit-version.jar, ant-junit4-version.jar then it works with me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had it when using data provider and one of the parameters had a new line character, like this:

```
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] invalidAdjustment() {
    return new Object[][]{
            {"some \n text", false},
            };
}
```

Removing the `\n` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was fretting with this and none of the answers helped me until i moved the test source file from this folder:

```
src/test/java/com/junit/test
```

up to this folder:

```
src/test/java/com/junit
```

Answer (score -1):

The other reason generally i see people having method parameters, remove any parameters you might have in the test method, regardless you add @Test annotation , you need to have your method name starting "test" in order for Junit to pick you testcase.
hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Test method name public void test**Name**() {}

Where  **name()** in source naming name methods.