# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, appium

I am new to Maven, and I am trying to do a test run with the below POM. mvn -compile command displays no errors but mvn -test command is throwing errors. Please find below for more details.

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/test/java/Test</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

MVN commands

mvn compile output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.953 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-15T10:51:07-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mvn test -e output

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/gowtham/Desktop/Projects/Test/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Test ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/gowtham/Desktop/Projects/Test/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running Test.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.009 sec <<< FAILURE!
warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in Test.AppTest
  at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
  at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:263)
  at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
  at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
  at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
  at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
  at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
  at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
  at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:95)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:121)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:98)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Failed tests:   warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1): No tests found in Test.AppTest

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.432 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-15T10:53:38-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project Test: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/gowtham/Desktop/Projects/Test/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project Test: There are test failures.

Please refer to /Users/gowtham/Desktop/Projects/Test/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /Users/gowtham/Desktop/Projects/Test/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:83)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:176)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:150)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:650)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:586)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
  ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Here is the java code:

```
package Test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App
 */
public class AppTest extends TestCase 
{
  @Test
public void Test() throws MalformedURLException 
{
  DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android device");
  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
  AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Could you please help resolve the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [junit: no tests found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469480/junit-no-tests-found)

Comment: You used junit 3.8.1 in Pom.xml and then imported org.junit.Test, How is that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no tests being found, you need to have at least a single test method in your project:

```
@Test
public void doTest() {};
```

Comment: I have a method in my java class but sadly it doesn't get executed. I have updated the class file on this now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using 4.12 version of junit in pom.xml and by removing the extends Testcase in the java file.