# gradle connectedAndroidTest returns "No test found", however adb shell am instrument can find the tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

We have a library project and multiple applications depends on it. And the unit tests are in the library project. 
We're able to run the tests from dependent projects in Android Studio, but

```
./gradlew :[DependentProject]:connectedAndroidTest
```

always returns "No test found, nothing to do”.

Through observation, I found in Android Studio, seems that it only executes gradle tasks:

```
:[DependentProject]:assembleDebug, :[DependentProject]assembleDebugTest
```

then uses adb to install the target and test apk, and adb shell am instruments to run the tests.

Since connectedAndroidTest depends on these two tasks, I install the target and test apks it produced, and manually invoked instrument command, tests got started.

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.package.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Then the question comes, where does connectedAndroidTest look for tests, and why it cannot find the tests while adb instrument can? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: When I get the no tests found error, oftentimes unplugging and replugging the device will fix it. (lame, but that's just what I've observed)

Comment: also, we run all the builds for our multi-library project with the command 'gradle connectedCheck'

Comment: Can you post your Gradle build configuration?
Have you got a block defining where you tests and java are? :
 sourceSets {
        main {....}
        androidTest {.....}
}

Comment: Do you have proguard enabled for instrumented tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue and I solve it by **add a method starting with "test"**

```
@Test
public void testWTF() throws Exception {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

And all other method with `@Test` annotation work too !

Amazing no ? I found the answer here : [No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332832/no-tests-found-with-test-runner-junit-4)

Comment: I remember that it's true that our tests don't start with "test", so that might be the reason, however I no longer have access to the code..... I thought for junit4 @Test annotation should be enough, but it seems not. Thank you.

Comment: Still, I'm not sure why those tests can be located by "adb shell am instrument" in my case, that may remain a mystery for a while...