# java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching

Tags: java, junit

My test class is below:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.hepeihui.service.UserService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/beans.xml"})
public class UserTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void addUserTest(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run it with JUnit, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=addUserTest], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=addUserTest(com.hepeihui.test.UserTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.hepeihui.test.UserTest,fLeadingIdentifier=addUserTest]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@17a83597
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

[image]

How can I resolve this error and get the tests running again?

Comment: can you rename your test case to be **testAddUser** instead of addUserTest. I want to see if adding the word test at the beginning make any difference.

Comment: You will most probably find an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332832/no-tests-found-with-test-runner-junit-4

Comment: Thank you very much.When i rename my test case to be testAddUser ,it doesn't make any difference.
At last ,I found my project loss a jar.

Comment: Good, you can write an answer for your own question describing how you solved it. You can then mark it as accepted.

Comment: I am sorry i don't know how to mark it as accepted.Could you tell me,Thanks.

Comment: You need to write an answer to your own question by clicking the link at the bottom of this page and then mark it as accepted. See here http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I have meet this error also,at least I found my junit test version is under 4.12,SpringJUnit4ClassRunner requires JUnit 4.12 or higher

Answer (score 1):

`aopaliance.jar` was missing so I added it.

The issue is now resolved.