# Why I am getting initialization error while running apache camel Test Case?

Tags: eclipse, junit, apache-camel

I am using below code for my Apache camel based application .  I am using JUNIT4 and camel version 2.18 . And I am running test case in my Eclipse IDE.
I am using MockEndPoint concept for testing my API

```
 package com.service;

import org.apache.camel.*;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FilterTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Override
    public boolean isDumpRouteCoverage() {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        String expectedBody = "<matched/>";

        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);

        template.sendBodyAndHeader(expectedBody, "foo", "bar");

        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendNotMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(0);

        template.sendBodyAndHeader("<notMatched/>", "foo", "notMatchedHeaderValue");

        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start").filter(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar")).to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }}
```

And I am getting below error for this code

```
FilterTest.testSendMatchingMessage
initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testSendMatchingMessage], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testSendMatchingMessage(com.service.FilterTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.service.FilterTest,fLeadingIdentifier=testSendMatchingMessage]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@255316f2

    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a camel issue but rather an eclipse / junit issue. Perhaps this is a duplicate of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332832/no-tests-found-with-test-runner-junit-4

Comment: maven based project it is working properly. But Normal Java project, it is not working I used the same version of dependency or I can say same version of a jar.