Java tests not found in Gradle project in VS code
I am trying to create a Java project on VScode with Gradle. I generated a gradle project in a workspace, which generated the following tree:
|-app
 | |-build.gradle.kts
 | |-src
 | | |-main
 | | | |-java
 | | | | |-test
 | | | | | |-App.java
 | | | |-resources
 | | |-test
 | | | |-java
 | | | | |-test
 | | | | | |-AppTest.java
 | | | |-resources
 |-.gitignore
 |-gradlew
 |-.gitattributes
 |-gradle
 | |-libs.versions.toml
 | |-wrapper
 | | |-gradle-wrapper.properties
 | | |-gradle-wrapper.jar
 |-gradlew.bat
 |-settings.gradle.kts

This generates a test file, but when I use the 'Java: Run tests' command it says that 'no tests found in this file'. Moreover, I get the following error on running the test from the Testing sidebar popup:
Failed to get workspace folder from test item: $(symbol-method) appHasAGreeting().
The screenshots can be found here (not enough reputation to post the images inline):
No test found message
Failed to get workspace folder error
The tests are run when I build with Gradle using ./gradlew build.
Here is the output from cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"


What am I doing wrong? And how do I fix it?
I tried opening the directory with the absolute path as suggested here. This still does not work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332832/no-tests-found-with-test-runner-junit-4

Hello, which testing framework are you using? If it's JUnit 4, you can try to check in build.gradle if plugins {    java}   dependencies {    testImplementation('junit:junit:(YOUR_JUNIT_VERSION)')}。 Then try reopening vscode and having it reload the project and see if that fixes the issue. Also, did you download Gradle for Java Extension? You can try to learn more about the test according to the documentation.
